# How to reload TableView in other View?

Tags: swift, core-data, tableview, reloaddata

I have some CoreData base wich I'm used in my TableView.

When I'm tried to clear those base in other View I have a message in my console log.

> CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.
>   Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

for deleting CoreData Array I'm used this code

```
self.historyArray.removeAll()
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "History")
fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

do {
    let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

    for managedObject in results
    {
        let managedObjectData:NSManagedObject = managedObject as! NSManagedObject 
        managedContext.deleteObject(managedObjectData)
    }
} catch {
    print("Detele all data")
}
```

I know I need to reload TableView, but how can I do this in other View?
ill tried this, but this code don't work.

```
var tableViewHistoryClass = HistoryView()
self.tableViewHistoryClass.tableView.reloadData()
```

Please help me to fix this message.

Comment: You don't need either notifications or delegates.  Your NSFetchedResultsController is already observing the deletions and crashing because they are not being handled correctly.  You just need to configure its delegate methods to either delete rows from the table when each object is deleted, or reload the table view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for answers!
I'm created new method, all my Clear CoreData function i added to my View in which i have TableView for showing all data from CoreData :P

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"clearCoreDataArray", name: "clearAllData", object: nil)

}

func clearCoreDataArray() {
historyArray.removeAll()
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "History")
        fetchRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

        do
        {
            let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
            for managedObject in results
            {
                let managedObjectData:NSManagedObject = managedObject as! NSManagedObject
                managedContext.deleteObject(managedObjectData)
            }
        } catch {
            print("Detele all data")
        }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

and in View when I'm need to use this method i use this code

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("clearAllData", object: self)
```

now i don't have any CoreData warnings

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve this by using notification.

1. create observer in viewDidLoad method where you can display your table view data.

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"refreshTableView", name: "reloadTable", object: nil)

   }

   func refreshTableView () {
       self.tableView.reloadData()
   }
   ```
2. Second view controller 
    -> In this view controller you can change your data( if you want to do) or send data object

   ```
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("reloadTable", object: nil)
   ```

   so like this it will reload your table view.

Comment: I delete my answer, it's the same like you :), this answer is enough

Comment: Warning, in Swift 2.0 using string literal for selector is deprecated. You should use #selector instead.

Comment: ill use your code but still have this message in my console log

Comment: CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

Comment: and only if i load the page with tableView before ill delete all data in my CoreData base

Comment: check your data source. because this approach is correct.

Comment: Are you updating any data from other view controller?

Comment: when I'm using tableView and delete all data from CoreData base in one ViewController i don't have any errors, this message i see only when I'm try to delete all data in CoreData base in second ViewController in which i dont have TableView
I'm using this code in ViewController with TableView
`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "tableReload", name: "relodTableView", object: nil)` in viewDidLoad() and add this function
`func tableReload() {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }`

Comment: and in ViewController in which ill deleting all data I'm using
`NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("relodTableView", object: self)`

Comment: you need to fetch data from database. and reload your table

Comment: bcoz one you deleting data from other view controller. it's deleting from your database. but you need to reload your data source.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to notify your tableview when data is removed.

When data is removed your code post notifications :

```
do {
    let results = try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)

    for managedObject in results
    {
        let managedObjectData:NSManagedObject = managedObject as! NSManagedObject 
        managedContext.deleteObject(managedObjectData)

        NSNotificationCenter
            .defaultCenter()
            .postNotificationName("dataDeleted", object: self)
    }
}
```

And in controller where is your tableview add an observer for this notification:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
     NSNotificationCenter
         .defaultCenter()
         .addObserver(
             self, 
             selector: #selector(viewController.reloadTableView), 
             name: "dataDeleted", 
             object: nil)
 }

 func reloadTableView() {
     self.tableview.reloadData
 }
```